# Possible passenger issue in sub uri

Tags: passenger, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have the following config:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Rails 3.2
- Ruby 1.9
- Passenger 4.0.37
- nginx (not sure of the version)

The app is humming away nicely using rvm

Now I'm trying to sub uri which has DIFFERENT ruby and rails versions.  I'm using this post as the template:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory

My main app is at www/gi and my sub uri is at www/r5

As a base test I have an index.html in both gi/public and r5/public.

I can http to gi/index.html AND gi/r5/index.html

I then created a simple 'start' controller in r5 with an index method and tried connecting via http to gi/r5/start/index.html.....and I get a 404 not found.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37;
    passenger_ruby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_app_env production;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen      80 default_server;
        return      444;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        #server_name  resys.gourmindia.com;
        server_name  134.213.29.174;
        root         /data/www/gi/public/;
        index        index.html;
        passenger_enabled on;
        #passenger_root /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37;
        #passenger_ruby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/wrappers/ruby;

#        location / {
#     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;     
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/r5(/.*|$) {
            alias /data/www/r5/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
            passenger_base_uri /r5;
            passenger_app_root /data/www/r5;
            passenger_document_root data/www/r5/public;
            passenger_ruby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby;
            passenger_enabled on;
    }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {

        }

    }
```

And here is the /opt/ningx/logs/error.log (last section - where I feel the fail occurs)

```
[ 2017-12-27 18:40:37.0095 15198/7fe1c970e700 Pool2/Pool.h:777 ]: Process (pid=15452, group=/data/www/r5#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
App 15463 stdout: 
App 15237 stderr: /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `trap'
App 15237 stderr: : 
App 15237 stderr: Invalid argument - SIGKILL
App 15237 stderr:  (
App 15237 stderr: Errno::EINVAL
App 15237 stderr: )
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `block in reset_signal_handlers'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `each_key'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `reset_signal_handlers'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:182:in `main_loop'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:161:in `<module:App>'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
[ 2017-12-27 18:40:42.0077 15198/7fe1c970e700 Pool2/Pool.h:777 ]: Process (pid=15463, group=/data/www/r5#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
App 15472 stdout: 
App 15237 stderr: /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `trap'
App 15237 stderr: : 
App 15237 stderr: Invalid argument - SIGKILL
App 15237 stderr:  (
App 15237 stderr: Errno::EINVAL
App 15237 stderr: )
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:356:in `block in reset_signal_handlers'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `each_key'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:354:in `reset_signal_handlers'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:182:in `main_loop'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:161:in `<module:App>'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 15237 stderr:   from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I found this on the phusionpassenger.com site:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_ruby

I did the following:

```
>which passenger-config
/home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/passenger-config

>rvm use 2.4.0
Using /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0

>/home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/passenger-config --ruby-command
```

The following error messages came up:

```
/home/nexargi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem passenger (>= 0.a) with executable passenger-config (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/nexargi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/passenger-config:23:in `<main>'
```

Please note that ruby 2.4.0 is the ruby required by the r5 sub-uri.  This does look like the problem.  However I don't know how to correct it.

Just to be absolutely certain I then did the following:

```
>rvm use 1.9.3-p484
Using /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484

>/home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/passenger-config --ruby-command
```

This gave the expected correct message:

```
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby
  Version: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby /home/nexargi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/bin/passenger start


## Notes for RVM users
Do you want to know which command to use for a different Ruby interpreter? 'rvm use' that Ruby interpreter, then re-run 'passenger-config --ruby-command'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the existing site's passenger was installed using RVM gem install etc. which is not the currently recommended way of doing things.

I found this:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/

I followed this and after removing the old passenger from inside RVM everything was fine again.